# (LMX)AMP and Laravel

Tags: php, macos, laravel, mamp

I understand LAMP, MAMP and XAMP are solution stack. I also understand there are frameworks like Laravel and Symfony.

If I have to start PHP development in a proper manner, Is it required to have a solution stack installed first and then the framework to have a professional set up?

If the answer is yes, then I am assuming the versions of the software inside the package is quite important for compatibility with the framework. Is there a popular combination out there?

And In Live, I suppose, I just to need to have the solution stack installed for the package to run.

My dev machine is a MAC with OSX 10.9.5 and my Live is going to be in Linux. I need to make sure these fundamental knowledge is concrete before I start the work. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Laravel has it's own Vagrant box for development called [Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead)

Answer (score 2):

Laravel has a all-in one virtual box solution. It's called as [Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead). Homestead works on many platforms such as Linux, MAC, Windows and contains everything you needed:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- PHP 5.6
- HHVM
- Nginx
- MySQL
- Postgres
- Node (With Bower, Grunt, and Gulp)
- Redis
- Memcached
- Beanstalkd
- Laravel Envoy
- Blackfire Profiler

If you decide to go with other solutions you will probably face with many problems like enabling essential extensions and with changing some system settings.

Besides you can use this solution for pretty much every kind of php framework or code.

Just follow the steps in the guide and almost everything will be ready to use just in few minutes after download finishes.

Comment: This is probably the best way to get started but my suggestion to the OP is to start getting familiar with PHP and MVC it not already before diving into Laravel.  That could become overwhelming.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is good choice as there is big community and Google trends show it is growing very fast.

As it is PHP then you need to have server which processes the PHP. Usually it is Apache2.

Many people like to use MAMP, XAMP to simplify their development. I prefer to use standard Apache2 myself and you can even just rely on Laravel/PHP builtin server that you can start with `php artisan serve`, It will be enough for defelopment purposes.